# I need to change the background of one cell in a table by clicking on a certain cell from another table.

Tags: html

What I am trying to do... let's say A is image1, B is image2, C is image3 and 
D is image4.  I need to click on the cell containing A and the second cell in the
other table would change the background to image1.  Click on the cell containing D...
the background in the second cell of the other table would change to image4.

```
<table><tr>
<td width="50" align="center">A</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="50" align="center">B</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="50" align="center">C</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="50" align="center">D</td>
</tr></table>
<BR><BR>
<table><tr>
<td width="50" align="center">unchanged</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="100" align="center">background color<br>changes when<br>A,B,C or D<br>
is clicked on.</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="50" align="center">unchanged</td>
</tr></table>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you'll need to use javascript.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: To be honest I am stumped.  I have used javascript but I am just starting to learn javascript to do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you need is to assign the "clickable" table cells a javascript function that will make the changes you desire using "onclick".  The "changing" table cells will require a unique ID for javascript to easily find and affect them.  In simplest form, the javascript function(s) will reside inside of `<script>` tags within the `<head>`.  Try something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function changeImage(id, image) {
            var ref = document.getElementById(id);
            ref.innerHTML = '<img src='+image+'>';
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border=1><tr>
         <td width="50" align="center"
            onclick="changeImage('myCell','image1.gif');">A</td>
         <td width="20"></td>
         <td width="50" align="center"
            onclick="changeImage('myCell','image2.gif');">B</td>
         <td width="20"></td>
         <td width="50" align="center"
            onclick="changeImage('myCell','image3.gif');">C</td>
         <td width="20"></td>
         <td width="50" align="center"
            onclick="changeImage('myCell','image4.gif');">D</td>
      </tr></table>
      <BR><BR>
      <table border=1><tr>
         <td width="50" align="center">unchanged</td>
         <td width="20" id="myCell"></td>
         <td width="100" align="center">background color<br>changes when<br>A,B,C or D<br>
         is clicked on.</td>
         <td width="20"></td>
         <td width="50" align="center">unchanged</td>
      </tr></table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have not addressed the background color, but I hope this gives you a start.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.  This made it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Give your tables each a unique id and use jquery .click and .html methods to change the contents.

```
$("#table1 tr td#a").click(function() {
 $("#table2 tr td:nth-of-type(2)").html("<img something.. >");
});
```

Comment: with my lack of script knowledge... can you please explain a little more.

Comment: Does this go in the <head>?

Comment: will this have to be repeated for b,c,d